# Multi Level Vertical Accordion Menu

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, menu

I'm trying to make a multi level vertical accordion menu but I keep failing :/ I'm new to client side programming.

This is my list:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>
        <li class="arrow"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Program</a></li>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Program at a Glance</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Theme and Keynote Speakers</a></li>
                <li class="arrow"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Call for Abstract</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class="arrow"><a href="javascript:void(0)" style="font-size:12px;">Abstract Guidelines</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" style="font-size:12px;">Submit Your Abstract</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Student Activities</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Pre-Congress Workshops</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Other Activities</a></li>
            </ul>
        <li class="arrow"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Refistration</a></li>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li ><a href="javascript:void(0)">Registration Information</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Official Letters of Invitation</a></li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Accomodation</a></li>
        <li class="arrow"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Sponsors & Exhibirtors</a></li>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Confirmed Sponsors</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Confirmed Exhibitors</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Why Become a Sponsor</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Sponsorship Opportunities</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Exhibit Opportunities</a></li>
                <li class="arrow"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Exhibitor Information</a></li>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li ><a href="javascript:void(0)">Floor Plane</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="javascript:void(0)">Exhibit Hours</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Manual</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </ul>
    </ul>  
</div>
```

And this is my function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sidebar ul li a').click(function (ev) {
        $('.sidebar .sub-menu').not($(this).parents('.sub-menu')).slideUp();
        $(this).next('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
        ev.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

That's my css, I'm just testing so the colors might be odd:

```
 .sidebar 
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        float:left;
        width: 180px;
    }

    li.arrow{
        background:#fff url(images/GCHERA/arrow-down.png) no-repeat right center;
    }

    .sidebar ul 
    {
        margin: 10px 0 0 0 ;
        padding: 0 0 0 10px;
        list-style: none;
        text-indent: 0px;
        display:block;
    }

    .sidebar li 
    {
        margin-top: 3px;

    }

        .sidebar>ul>li 
        {
            background-color:red;
        }


    .sidebar a 
    {
        font: 16px;
        color: #008c44;
        display: block;
        height: 32px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .sidebar a:hover 
    {
        text-decoration: underline;
        padding-left:5px;
    }

    .sidebar ul ul {
    display:none;   
    }     

     .sidebar>ul>li>ul
    {
        background-color:green;
    }

    .sidebar>ul>li>ul>li 
    {
        background-color:green;
    }

     .sidebar>ul>li>ul>li>ul
    {
        background-color:blue;
    }

    .sidebar>ul>li>ul>li>ul>li
    {
        background-color:blue;
    }
```

It only allows the first occurrence to open. Please any help? I'm new to menus and jQuery.

This is the fiddle I used: http://jsfiddle.net/jfzx7/

Comment: Maybe include your css as well?

Comment: I've included them as demanded hope it will help...it would be nice to clear up my mistake if possible

Comment: Another thing to check out: Your sub-lists should be inside <li> elements, not directly inside the parent <ul>.  Changing this may affect your .not() selector, so review that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with your HTML, please check and align it properly. find corresponding fiddle.

Comment: Issue is with your HTML, please check and align it properly. find corresponding fiddle. 
[DEMO LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/RT9WL/33/)

Comment: Could you please fix the link for the demo ?

Comment: Its giving me an error of the jsfiddle code, not sure where i have made wrong.. more likely i am going to remove the "[DEMO][1]", my apologies

Comment: Ty for your answer but in Program > Call for Abstract, if I want to add another inner UL can't I just add it directly ?

Comment: @subhkriti Like the error message says `Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code.`

Comment: I mean here I have only 3 layers, if I want to add a fourth one how to solve it ?

Comment: Hi, Its simple just add another UL inside your Li, like I have did here. I have added Ul in "Call for Abstract". please check the updated Fiddle [Demo Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/RT9WL/35/)

Comment: Just click on Call for Abstract -> Submit your Abstract. Your 4th layer .. Cheers :)